# Gostaria de saber se estou fazendo esse ajax da forma certa?

Tags: php, ajax

Galera, eu tenho esse ajax e uma pagina chamada test.php que recebe um value, gostaria de saber se meu ajax está certo e esse value está sendo pego corretamento dentro da pagina test.php

```
<script>
  $('input[name=valor]').click(function() {  
var campoRadio =  $('input[name=valor]:checked').val();


$.ajax({
   method: "POST",
   data: { campoRadio: campoRadio },
   url: "test.php",
   dataType: "php"

});
 alert(campoRadio);

});


  </script>
```

test.php

```
$valor = $_POST["campoRadio"];
```

Comment: Sim, está fazendo certo, basta colocar um `success: function(data){}` para ter o retorno do `php` e executar alguma ação

Comment: Esse `dataType: "php"` que não fez muito sentido, só. Com ele você informará ao jQuery qual é o tipo de retorno esperado na resposta. Normalmente é *text*, *html*, *json* ou *xml*.

Comment: Eu acho que com esse código não está passando o valor `campoRadio`  para a pagina `test.php`, O que mais faz a pagina `test.php` além de pegar o valor vindo do formulário? Executa  alguma rotina com o  `$valor`  para carregar algo dentro da  página do ajax? Ou somente quer passar o valor para `test.php`?

Comment: Leo, esse test seria um pagseguro.php, e eu envio é o valor de um plano pra dentro dela, porém não está funcionando, me parece que eu recebo o valor dentro do pagseguro.php, mas o pagseguro não consegue rodar!!

Answer (score 2):

Esta certo sim, só falta o tratamento do retorno. (success, error) Segue exemplo:

```
$.ajax({
   method: "POST",
   data: { campoRadio: campoRadio },
   url: "test.php",
   success:function(data){
       //Coloque aqui o codigo que desejar, lembrando que ele cai aqui caso o retorno seja OK e a variavel data trás para vc o retorno da url chamada
   }

});
```

Detalhe: Esse dataType ta meio errado, ele serve pra dizer se o retorno é texto ou json ou algum outro objeto em questão. no caso vc pode remover ele

Answer (score -1):

Acredito que a maneira correta seria:

```
script>


 $('input[name=valor]').click(function() {  
var _campoRadio =  $('input[name=valor]:checked').val();

  $.ajax({
    method: "post",
    url: "meu_script.php",
    data: {campoRadio : _campoRadio},
  });
```

Procurei sempre diferenciar o nome das variaveis para não se confundir